# Android ArrayAdapter null object reference error while scrolling up again

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

[update]
Here's the link to the very simple project to view code
[Download Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fK84knaywBYvzaAFuz-PEIzt8k_8ptzv/view?usp=sharing)

I'm creating a custom adapter with radio buttons. when the list view gets displayed I get no error but once I scroll up again to display the first hidden radio group I get

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioButton.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

when I set the text for the first radio button in the new radio group

Here's the list_item

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/q_text"
    android:text="question"
    style="@style/q_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/q_answers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <RadioButton
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q_option1"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q_option2"/>

    <RadioButton
        android:text="text"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/q_option3"/>

</RadioGroup>

<Button
    style="@style/view_answer_btn"
    android:id="@+id/view_answer_btn"
    android:text="@string/view_answer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And the Adapter

```
public class QuestionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Questions> {

    public QuestionsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Questions> questions) {
        super(context, 0, questions);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View listItemView = convertView;
        if (listItemView == null) {
            listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        }

        Questions currentQuestion = getItem(position);

        TextView questionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_text);
        questionTextView.setText( currentQuestion.getmQuestionTitle());

        RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_answers);

        RadioButton firstAnswer = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_option1);
        firstAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1() );
        firstAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1()));

        RadioButton secondAnswer = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_option2);
        secondAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer2() );
        secondAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer2()));

        RadioButton thirdAnswer = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_option3);
        thirdAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer3() );
        thirdAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer3()));

        return listItemView;
    }
}
```

The error is fired at this line

```
firstAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1() );
```

Why I get the error here which means it can't find the firstAnswer radio button though the list is displayed correctly when running the activity before scrolling

[image]

Comment: Please add stacktrace from exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll listview your radio button will be null with your code. Your project will work when you will fix your project just as below code.

```
    @NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = 
  LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        try {
            Questions currentQuestion = getItem(position);

             viewHolder.questionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_text);
             viewHolder.questionTextView.setText(currentQuestion.getmQuestionTitle());

             viewHolder.radioGroup = (RadioGroup) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_answers);

            viewHolder.firstAnswer = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_option1);
            viewHolder.firstAnswer.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1());
            viewHolder.firstAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1()));

            viewHolder.secondAnswer = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_option2);
            viewHolder.secondAnswer.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer2());
            viewHolder.secondAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer2()));
            viewHolder.thirdAnswer = (RadioButton) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_option3);
            viewHolder.thirdAnswer.setText(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer3());
            viewHolder.thirdAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer3()));

Button viewAnswer = (Button) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.view_answer_btn);
    viewAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) listItemView.getTag();
    }

    return listItemView;
}
private class ViewHolder {
    TextView questionTextView;
    RadioGroup radioGroup;
    RadioButton firstAnswer, secondAnswer,thirdAnswer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. But why Android can't find the radio button? is this normal or a bug?

Comment: because of you used to your code used to lisview.And your code block was missing.When you scroll listview bottom and up .After all line will create again all position.You should use recylerview more than better listview.https://medium.com/@manuaravindpta/what-is-the-difference-between-listview-and-recyclerview-bcd82c64ffbb

Comment: isn't this a recylerview? that's what I learned from udacity using the adapter. I will read that thank you

Comment: it is not recylerview.it is listview.However, those are displaying for list with adapter  but recylerview is much more flexiable and useful.

Comment: please have a look at this it's the same project but another issue displaying the answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55281600/android-listview-with-arrayadapter-replacing-list-item-components

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing a reference to your RadioButtons like this instead. Notice the difference in the `findViewById()` calls:

```
public class QuestionsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Questions> {

public QuestionsAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<Questions> questions) {
    super(context, 0, questions);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View listItemView = convertView;
    if (listItemView == null) {
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    Questions currentQuestion = getItem(position);

    TextView questionTextView = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_text);
    questionTextView.setText( currentQuestion.getmQuestionTitle());

    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.q_answers);

    RadioButton firstAnswer = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.q_option1);
    firstAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1() );
    firstAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1()));

    RadioButton secondAnswer = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.q_option2);
    secondAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer2() );
    secondAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer2()));

    RadioButton thirdAnswer = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.q_option3);
    thirdAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer3() );
    thirdAnswer.setId(Integer.parseInt(currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer3()));

    return listItemView;
}
```

}

Comment: RadioButton firstAnswer = (RadioButton) radioGroup.findViewById(R.id.q_option1);
        firstAnswer.setText( currentQuestion.getQuestionAnswer1() );  Same error